# Disk Utility not finding disk

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, disk-utility

I have an external drive that was dropped.  It doesn't mount anymore on my OS X box and Disk Utility doesn't see it. Is this the point where I'd need to bring it somewhere for expensive data recover?

Comment: Does the external drive power on when connected? If not, it must've been broken from the drop. <br>
Try connecting it to another source to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, if the platters were spinning when it was dropped, the heads may have crashed and recovery may be impossible. If the drive was powered down, it's more likely that a wire or solder joint (or circuit board) is broken.

It could be a cheap five minute fix, or a "throw it out and get a new one". Either way, someone will have to crack the case and take a look.